# How to implement Function.prototype.apply without using apply?

Tags: javascript

```
function sumArguments () {
  var value = this instanceof Number ? this : 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    value += arguments[i];
  }
  return value;
}

Function.prototype.apply1 = function() {
  var fn = this;
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  var context = args.shift();
  var newArgs = args[0];

  var boundfn = fn.bind(context, newArgs);

  return boundfn();
}

console.log(sumArguments.apply1(4, [1, 2, 3])); --> should equal 10
```

How can one implement apply without using apply? I'm getting stuck on how to transform the array of [1,2,3] to be passed in as 1,2,3 to bind.

Comment: *"without using apply"* Why?

Comment: Other than using `eval()` after constructing a string of code, it would likely require a native extension of the engine itself. The native [`Call()` function](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-call) and [`[[Call]]` methods](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist) that define a function's ability to be invoked behave similarly to [`.apply()`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function.prototype.apply), accepting an `argumentsList`. Spreading the arguments is actually counter-productive.

Comment: You shouldn't use fn.bind because it returns new function with hard-coded context. While context is hard coded you can't invoke function with native apply or call.

Answer (score 1):

Only way I could think of is using `eval`.

```js
function apply(fn, args){
  var stringArgs = args.reduce(function(acc, el, i){
    var argString = 'args[' + i + ']';
    return acc += i === 0 ? argString : ',' + argString; 
  });
  return eval('fn(' + stringArgs + ')');
}
       
function test(first, second, third){
    console.log(first, second, third);
}

apply(test, [1, 2, 3]);
```

Although, I can't figure why would you need this. This also doesn't work with many data types like objects or strings. It does works for numbers though.

**Edit**: Now it works for any data type.

Answer (score 1):

Your goal here is to call `fn.bind` with the context and the provided arguments, right?

If you're using ES6, the spread operator `...` is what you want:

```
foo(...[1,3,5]); //equivalent to foo(1, 3, 5)

fn.bind(context, ...args);
```

Otherwise, you can call `apply` on `bind`:

```
fn.bind.apply(fn, [context].concat(args));
```

Passing `fn` as the context of `fn.bind` will preserve its normal behavior, and you need to combine all of the arguments that you want to pass to bind into a single array, hence the concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you'll need to use apply, but here's the sum function to give you what you want.  It should be able to handle many inner arrays and ignore objects.

```
function sumArguments() {
    var value = this instanceof Number ? this : 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        if (typeof arguments[i] === 'number') {
            value += arguments[i];
        } else if (typeof arguments[i] === 'object' &&
                   typeof arguments[i].length !== 'undefined') {
            for (var j = 0; j < arguments[i].length; j++) {
                if (typeof arguments[i][j] === 'number') {
                    value += arguments[i][j];
                } else if (typeof arguments[i][j] === 'object' &&
                           typeof arguments[i][j].length !== 'undefined') {
                    value += sumArguments(arguments[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return value;
}

console.log(sumArguments(4, [1, 2, 3, [7, 8]], 5, 'a', 2));
```